# EFCodefirst: Define Unique Key (UK) Automatically rather than Direct way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I Use MVC3 and EFCodefirst, for define UKs I use the following codes in drived class of  `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MYDBModel>` at Global.asax file:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_Contact_AddressKind_Title ON
Addresses (Title, Contact_Id, AddressKind_Id)");
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_Member_Title ON Addresskinds
(Title, Member_Id)");
```

Is there any way to automatically define UKs in overriding `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` Method in MYDBModel?? I don't know exactly, maybe in some way like `modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().....`??

Answer (score 3):

No. EF has no support for unique keys so your approach with defining keys in database initializer is the best you can get.